# TypeError: prc.cng() is not a function in Firefox, Uncaught TypeError: Object #<HTMLInputElement> has no method 'cng' in Chrome

Tags: javascript

I am writing a small library for internal use in a project that I am working on, I am an amateur Javascript developer, so mind my mistakes please.

I have written a small html file as well as javascript below it goes,

```
<html>
 <head>
  <script>
    var prc = {
      cng : function(evt){
           console.log(evt);
      }
    }
  </script>
 </head>
 <body>
   <input type='text' id='prc' onkeydown="prc.cng(window.event)"/>
 <body>
</html>
```

I tried executing this in Firefox and Chrome, not in IE Still,

When I am trying in Firefox, it gives this error `"TypeError: prc.cng is not a function"`, and when trying in chrome it gives the `"Uncaught TypeError: Object #<HTMLInputElement> has no method 'cng'"`.

I tried searching for this in StackOverflow, but the issues they are facing is quite different from what I am facing. Almost most of the issues faced were with jQuery involved, here please note that I am not using any kind of library and writing with plain old Javascript.

Any Help would be appreciated to enhance my understanding of the issue.

Comment: It works fine for me in Chrome 27: http://jsfiddle.net/barmar/BWfA7/

Comment: The error you're getting from Chrome implies that you're changing the value of `prc` somewhere, it's being set to an `<input>` element. Check your script for variable reuse.

Comment: The fiddle seems to be working fine :) . Ok I am using chrome 24 and Firefox 18.0. Can't seem to understand why this is happening :(

Comment: This is trivial code, I doubt that it matters what version you're running. Is this really your entire page?

Comment: @Barmar, that was insightful, i tried running only this code and it works. But if its included as part of the rest of the code that I have written. It doesn't work.

Comment: Like I said, something in the rest of the code is reusing the variable `prc`. Search for `prc =` in your code.

Comment: Really strange, I checked the whole code. As well as the html, there is no place where I have defined prc variable except for this definition.

Comment: Try renaming `prc` and see if that fixes it.

Comment: yeah!.. Thanks, got it atlast, the problem was with text input. Here while giving an example i have given it as pr, but in the actual html i have written as prc itself. So from this i understand that, javascript actually creates an object for each id defined in the page. Now when i defined an id for the html element, it was overwriting the actual price object that I had written in the javascript. :) . There goes a good 2 hours of my time and some of yours figuring out a trivial problem :)

Comment: Changed the question so that it actually gives the problem. And the solution will post. :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Having an element with an `id` that is the same as an existing JS variable is blatting the content of the variable and replacing it with a reference to the element.

The quick solution is to change either the variable name or the element id.

---

A more robust solution would be to keep all your data in as narrow a scope as possible. If you don't desperately need it to be global, then don't make it global and it won't be over-writable from outside the script.

Since, using intrinsic event attributes, you can only refer to variables in `<script>` elements if they are global, this is also a good time to stop using them and move to something modern.

```
// Self-executing anonymous function expression used to limit scope
(function () { 

    // Locally scoped prc that won't clash with the element
    var prc = {
      cng : function(evt){
           console.log(evt);
      }
    }

    // Event handler binding
    document.getElementById('prc').addEventListener('keydown', function (evt) {
        prc.cng(evt)
    });

}());
```

Note that this script doesn't delay execution until `load` or `domReady` so place it **after** the input so that the input exists when the attempt to find the event handler happens.

Answer (score 0):

I have found the answer to my own question, thanks to @Barmar, who has been instrumental in making me understand the problem.

When i define any element in html like this

```
<input type='text' id='test' onkeydown='test.fn()'/>
```

It means that an object is created by the browser for the same. So If I have javascript written which clashes with the id, that won't be accessible anywhere in that page.

```
<script>
  var test = {
    fn : function(){
       console.log('test');
     }
  }
</script>
```

So Ideally either rename the id, or rename the object.