# Javascript class "Object #<HTMLInputElement> has no method 'addTag'"

Tags: javascript, jquery

I've worked with javascript for a long enough time, and this is the first time I've ever been completely stumped as to what is wrong.

```
Object #<HTMLInputElement> has no method 'addTag'
```

So, here is the javascript file.

```
function actions(){
    var main = this;

    this.addTag = function(){
        var sTag = $('#sTag').val();
        if(sTag!=''){
            var i = $('#tag-list li').length+1;
            var html = '<li id="tag_'+i+'">';
                html+= '    <input type="hidden" name="sTags" value="'+sTag+'" />'+sTag;
                html+= '    <a href="#" class="small button delete" title="Remove tag" onclick="act.removeTag('+i+');return false;"></a>';
                html+= '</li>';
            $('#tag-list ul').append(html);
            $('#tag-list').show();
        }
    }
    this.removeTag = function(i){
        $('#tag_'+i).remove();
        if($('#tag-list li').length==0){
            $('#tag-list').hide();
        }
    }
}
```

Relatively basic. The javascript file is included in the page like so

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="scripts.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">
    var act = new actions();
</script>
```

Then further down the page in the form, there is a basic system to add a tag to a list

```
<input type="text" id="sTag" name="sTag" size="30" class="text left" style="margin:5px 4px 0 0;" value="" />
<a href="#" class="short medium button" onclick="act.addTag();return false;"><span class="tick"></span>Add</a>
```

This is meant to add a new tag to a list, the list is then saved when the form is submitted.

I've only shown relevant parts due to the overall size of the page.

I've used this setup, although with different functions, dozens or hundreds of times before without trouble. I don't think it's a caching issue as the issue exists on different devices and browsers which have never accessed the page before.

Any help is greatly appreciated!

Comment: seems fine to me http://jsfiddle.net/arunpjohny/4zxuN/1/

Comment: possible duplicate of [TypeError: prc.cng() is not a function in Firefox, Uncaught TypeError: Object #<HTMLInputElement> has no method 'cng' in Chrome](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16581252/typeerror-prc-cng-is-not-a-function-in-firefox-uncaught-typeerror-object)

Comment: The jsfiddle version works, but not my own still. Really confused now. I also asumed that other post was not enough the same due to code/structure, despite ultimately having pretty much the same error.

Answer (score 0):

It is working here

```
function actions(){

    this.addTag = function(){
        alert('add');
       var sTag = $('#sTag').val();
        if(sTag!=''){
            var i = $('#tag-list li').length+1;
            var html = '<li id="tag_'+i+'">';
                html+= '    <input type="hidden" name="sTags" value="'+sTag+'" />'+sTag;
                html+= '    <a href="#" class="small button delete" title="Remove tag" onclick="act.removeTag('+i+');return false;"></a>';
                html+= '</li>';
            $('#tag-list ul').append(html);
            $('#tag-list').show();
        } 
    }
    this.removeTag = function(i){
       $('#tag_'+i).remove();
        if($('#tag-list li').length==0){
            $('#tag-list').hide();
        } 

    }
}


  act = new actions();
```

check this jsFiddle.
http://jsfiddle.net/Uf9y6/2/

Can you tell me which browser you are using to test?

Comment: Tested in Chrome and IE10, Chrome on multiple devices.