# Javascript function not called when id and function name same

Tags: javascript, html

I want know the what is the effect of `id` and `function` when both are same. Example:

```
<tr> <td><img id='deleteAuthor' onclick='javascript: deleteAuthor(this)' src='images/close.png' /></td></tr>";
        function deleteAuthor(element){
            alert(element);
        }
    output:TypeError: deleteAuthor is not a function
    [Break On This Error]   


    <tr> <td><img id='deleteAuthorbt' onclick='javascript: deleteAuthor(this)' src='images/close.png' /></td></tr>";
       function deleteAuthor(element){
        alert(element);
      }
    output:Object HTMLImageElement
```

Please Why it behave so?

Comment: it is because both the element id and the function are colliding in the global scope resulting in the element overriding the function reference

Comment: more read http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3434278/ie-chrome-are-dom-tree-elements-global-variables-here

Comment: possible duplicate of [TypeError: prc.cng() is not a function in Firefox, Uncaught TypeError: Object #<HTMLInputElement> has no method 'cng' in Chrome](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16581252/typeerror-prc-cng-is-not-a-function-in-firefox-uncaught-typeerror-object)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

U have to use different names for id and function. Same names for both will cause ambiguity

Comment: It isn't ambiguous, the scoping and overriding rules are consistent. A better solution is to avoid doing everything in the global scope.